# Oracle.DataAccess.dll not shown in explorer although it is installed in GAC

Tags: oracle, .net-assembly, gac, odp.net

Does anybody know why my Oracle.DataAccess.dll Version 4 assemblies are not shown in explorer view. It is installed in GAC and working without any problems. `gacutil` shows it as expected.

[image]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>gacutil /l Oracle
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.18020
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:

Number of items = 0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>gacutil /l Oracle.DataAccess
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.18020
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86

Number of items = 8

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>
```

Comment: The first digit of the version number just means that it uses .NET 4.0 vs 2.0. Make sure the explorer is somehow not set up to show only .NET 2.0 assemblies.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the answer here: [Gacutil.exe successfully adds assembly, but assembly not viewable in explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054304/gacutil-exe-successfully-adds-assembly-but-assembly-not-viewable-in-explorer-w)