# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, .net-4.5.2

I am working on .net 4.5.2 console application and using odp.net to connect to database. Things are working absolutely fine in my local system. However getting the below error on DEV server. I have checked all my projects are set as X64 and the oracle.dataccess dll is available in c:\widnows\mircosoft.net\assembly.
But to no avail. I think I have tried all possible permutations and combinations.

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Oracle client? I've had these sorts of issues before and uninstalling the client and then reinstalling it fixed it.

Comment: You can use the Global Assembly Cache Tool to show you what versions it thinks are loaded and ensure that specific version is installed: `GACUTIL.EXE /L ORACLE.DATAACCESS`

Comment: executing the gacutil on server says not recognized as internal command

Comment: sorry but Its a DEV server I dont have any control to install or uninstall anything

Comment: I have also checked the c:\widnows\microsoft. net\assembly folder and see the necessary assemblies

Comment: Where is `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` installed? It is `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\...` (and not in GAC_32)? Ensure that you run the 64 bit version of `GACUTIL.EXE` in case you use it. Does the DEV server has an 64 bit Oracle Client installed? Note, Windows Explorer shows only .NET version 2 assemblies in `C:\Windows\assembly`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213105/oracle-dataaccess-dll-not-shown-in-explorer-although-it-is-installed-in-gac

Comment: Yes Wernfried 64 bit oracle client is installed on the server

Comment: Is it also version 4.112.3.0 of Oracle.DataAccess.dll you have on your local system? You can also put a simple copy of Oracle.DataAccess.dll to application folder.